# Why does surrounding my class with a namespace cause all other classes to stop compiling?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, namespaces

I have a large web app in vb.net 4.0.  Its default namespace is configured in its project properties.  None of the root-level classes in our app are surrounded by namespace declarations.

When I add a .asmx file to the root folder of the website, it compiles fine, but it doesn't work for some reason (already asked why in other topics).  So to get it to work, I try to surround the class declared in the .asmx by a namespace declaration.   As soon as I do this, I go from zero compiler errors to about a zillion.  My app can't find ANYTHING in the root namespace.  But I haven't changed any other files, only this .asmx file.

WHY is it behaving this way?  How do I prevent it from behaving this way without refactoring the entire app?  I would love to blank out the default namespace and add them explicitly around every root-level class, but I'm not sure that would fly with our release manager, and I don't even know if it would fix the problem...

Comment: Open the .asmx file with a text editor and check the Class and CodeBehind settings.

Comment: Here is the complete plaintext in Homepage.asmx.  I have removed the project name and replaced with PROJECT_NAME because I'm not sure I can divulge publicly.   Incidentally, if I try removing that PROJECT_NAME and the subsequent ".", I get a runtime error about not being able to load type HomepageService. <%@ WebService Language="vb" CodeBehind="HomepageService.asmx.vb" Class="PROJECT_NAME.HomepageService" %>

Comment: If you add a namespace, then you need to add the namespace to the class value within the .asmx page.  So it reads Namespace.HomepageService

Comment: That doesn't look like and asmx (WebService) file? It should look something like this: <%@ WebService Language="vb" CodeBehind="WebService1.asmx.vb" Class="WebApplication1.WebService1" %>

Comment: @rontornambe that looks the exact same as what I posted?  Although two minutes after my original post, I corrected it, so maybe you saw the original...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a namespace in VB.net around a class you have to update any references to the namespace.

As an example.  If you add a namespace of `Bar` around a class named "candy", and the Root namespace is `Foo` (can be found in project properties -> Application -> Root namespace) you would now need to add a `Import Foo.Bar` to any classes that were referencing it.

So, for the case of your asmx markup file, if your root namespace is `Foo`, and the namespace wrapper you added to your webservice was `Bar` you'll need to update your .asmx mark up to:

```
<%@ WebService Language="vb" CodeBehind="HomepageService.asmx.vb" Class="Foo.Bar.HomepageService" %>
```

Comment: Yeah, okay, of course, but that doesn't stop the compiler errors from appearing for all the other classes ...   I'll explain again...  I add namespace Foo around a class named "candy", and the root namespace is also Foo...  As soon as I do this, all other classes in my root namespace (except candy) cause compiler errors.  I did change my .asmx file to read Class="Foo.Foo.Candy".  The reason I am adding the namespace around my webservice is that all the examples I've seen of webservices, and all the troubleshooting advice I've read, says the namespace must be declared explicitly.

Comment: This question I've posted here is a side-question of my main problem, which is getting the damn webservice to receive calls from javascript.  The question on this page is just to ask why putting that Foo namespace around a single class causes all other classes to fail build..

Comment: I've got one vb.net project with 20 working webservices that don't have explicit namespaces, so it's definitely not 100% necessary.  That said, it still seems odd.  Have you tried doing a clean solution and rebuild solution?  Sometimes this will fix weird compile errors.

Comment: I got the webservice working, but I haven't figured out why the weird behaviour.  In the working version, the root namespace is implicit and I have avoided declaring any explicit namespaces.